# Command that displays the symbol written

Tags: macros, enumerate, babel, quotation

I wrote a list and want it to display `* "bok" til` (imagine that * is an orange star), but instead, the output is `* boktil`. I think it has something to do with the `[nynorsk]{babel}` package or the wishlist environment? Here's the code (the problem is `\item "bok" til`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,enumitem,amssymb,pifont}

\newenvironment{wishlist}{
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\color{orange}$\bigstar$}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textendash}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\alph{enumiv}}
    \begin{enumerate}}
    {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{wishlist}
    \item "bok" til
\end{wishlist}

\end{document}
```

Then my question is: Is there a command that allows the symbols to be displayed in the PDF as they are written in LaTeX? Maybe a command that works for all kinds of symbols?

(I tried `\"` but that gave two dots over the `b` and two dots over the `t`) Also, a wierd thing is if you replace `bok` with `h` and `til` with `h` it gives `* "h"h`.

Comment: The character " can be typeset with `\textquotedbl` in LaTeX. You should, however, perhaps rather use typographically correct quotation marks (for Norwegian those should be either `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright` — «…» — or `\quotedblbase` and `\textquotedblleft` — „…“).

Comment: \textquotedbl causes the same problem as " does. It doesn't work.

Comment: You could try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with `\textquotedbl`. But I guess, this is not the best solution …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are made an active character in norwegian. To use them, babel defines the shortcut `\dq`. Other than this, I took the opportunity to simplify your code, using the functionalities of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, nynorsk]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,enumitem,amssymb,pifont}
\usepackage[autostyle, norwegian=quotes]{csquotes}

\newlist{wishlist}{enumerate}{4}
    \setlist[wishlist, 1]{label=$\bigstar$, font=\color{orange}}
    \setlist[wishlist, 2]{label=\roman*}
    \setlist[wishlist, 3]{label=\textendash}
    \setlist[wishlist, 4]{label=\alph*}

\begin{document}

\begin{wishlist}
    \item \dq bok\dq til
\end{wishlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how do you get \ in Norwegian? I tried \char`\\ and it gave (surprisingly) " .

Comment: No, it is kind of a separate question, but related. If I want to write \ in the text, how to I do that? Is there a command like \backslash or?

Comment: The command is `\textbackslash`.